# Bake All Physics in a Scene at the Same Time

Tags: physics

Is it possible to bake the physics on all simulations in a scene at the same time? For example, I have 12 flags that blow in the wind. I want to be able to delete bake/bake all of the simulations at the same time when I make edits. Currently I'm selecting each object, one a time and baking the simulation. I was hoping to find a faster way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Go to the Scene settings and create a Rigid Body World then hit Bake All Dynamics:

[image]

[image]

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Assuming you're using cloth dynamics, just scroll to the bottom of the Cloth settings in the Physics tab and choose "Bake All Dynamics."

[image]

[image]

Comment: i just wanted to add that the back all dynamics button is also in cloth simulation. You don't have to add a rigid body system for cloth simulation, if you don't use rigid bodies (like in his example, he is just using cloth - i guess)

Comment: Ahh good point @Chris, I didn't think that through. I have updated my answer, cheers.

Comment: When I choose the Bake All Dynamics button it only bakes the simulation on one of the flags. I have 12 in the scene. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious. What I want to accomplish is to bake each of the 12 separate flags at the same time without having to select each object and performing this action 12 times.

Comment: Sorry @TroyMcClellan, I will update my answer with another solution, which is technically for Rigid Body dynamics but should work in this case as well.